# compiling NW extension in NetLogo

Tags: scala, netlogo

I am trying to compile the NW extension after cloning from git, I have this stack trace:

```
NW-Extension git:(5.x) sbt clean package
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/digitaldust/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/Users/digitaldust/.sbt/0.13/plugins/}global-plugins...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/digitaldust/Desktop/LOCAL/NW-Extension/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/digitaldust/Desktop/LOCAL/NW-Extension/project/}nw-extension-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to nw-extension (in build file:/Users/digitaldust/Desktop/LOCAL/NW-Extension/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 5-apr-2016 18.18.47
[info] Updating {file:/Users/digitaldust/Desktop/LOCAL/NW-Extension/}nw-extension...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 42 Scala sources to /Users/digitaldust/Desktop/LOCAL/NW-Extension/target/scala-2.9.2/classes...
[error] error while loading CharSequence, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken
[error] (bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 10)
[error] error while loading AnnotatedElement, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.class)' is broken
[error] (bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 76)
[error] error while loading ConcurrentMap, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.class)' is broken
[error] (bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 61)
[error] error while loading Comparator, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/util/Comparator.class)' is broken
[error] (bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 20)
[error] /Users/digitaldust/Desktop/LOCAL/NW-Extension/src/main/org/nlogo/extensions/nw/algorithms/CentralityMeasurer.scala:19: could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[Double]
[error]         turtle -> (lastScore + (inNeighbors(turtle) map last).sum)
[error]                                                               ^
[error] /Users/digitaldust/Desktop/LOCAL/NW-Extension/src/main/org/nlogo/extensions/nw/algorithms/ClusteringMetrics.scala:21: could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[Int]
[error]       neighborLinkCounts.sum.toDouble / (neighbors.size * (neighbors.size - 1))
[error]                          ^
[error] error while loading Entry, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/util/Map$Entry.class)' is broken
[error] (bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 10)
[error] /Users/digitaldust/Desktop/LOCAL/NW-Extension/src/main/org/nlogo/extensions/nw/jung/io/GraphMLImport.scala:170: value getKey is not a member of java.util.Map.Entry[edu.uci.ics.jung.io.graphml.Metadata.MetadataType,java.util.List[edu.uci.ics.jung.io.graphml.Key]]
[error]             .asScala.map(entry => entry.getKey -> entry.getValue.asScala).toMap
[error]                                         ^
[error] 8 errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 8 s, completed 5-apr-2016 18.18.55
```

any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: While NetLogo 5.3.x now _runs_ on Java 8, it still needs to be compiled with a Java 6 JDK (and so do extensions). It looks like your compiling with Java 8. I _think_ that pointing your `JAVA_HOME` to Java 6 would be sufficient to fix your problem...

Comment: thanks very much, I'll try immediately

Comment: should I change something int the build.sbt?

Comment: I mean, I have now installed Java 6 for Mac OS X, can I change something in the build.sb? I'd prefer to hardwire it for this build than to change my java home since I am running other stuff that needs Java 8

Comment: I'm not sure if you can hardwire it in `build.sbt`, but you can probably use `env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle ./sbt` to run `sbt` (adjust the path as needed...)

Comment: worked! right path for Mac OS X is `env JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/home ./sbt clean package` 
if you want to write the answer, I'll be happy to accept it... thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While NetLogo 5.3.x now runs on Java 8, it still needs to be compiled with a Java 6 JDK (and so do extensions). Judging from your output, it looks like you're trying to compile against `jdk1.8.0_65`.

The solution should be as simple as pointing your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the location of a Java 6 JDK. If you don't want to modify `JAVA_HOME` permanently, you can use the `env` command to run `sbt`, e.g.:

```
env JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/home ./sbt clean package
```